# Error: Installation has failed

Tags: ubuntu, ros-humble

i am new to here and Ros2
i am using UBUNTU 22.04 on lenovo latop with amd and ros2 humble
while updating getting the below error , can any one help me to solve it , if any more information i am ready to provide
Error: Installation has failed.
If you’d like to file a bug report please include ‘/var/log/nala/dpkg-debug.log’

Error: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/ros-humble-generate-parameter-library-example_0.3.8-1jammy.20240311.113305_amd64.deb (–unpack):

Error: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/ros-humble-generate-parameter-library-example_0.3.8-1jammy.20240311.113305_amd64.deb (–unpack):
trying to overwrite ‘/opt/ros/humble/include/admittance_controller_parameters/admittance_controller_parameters.hpp’, which is also in package ros-humble-admittance-controller 2.33.0-1jammy.20240311.114411
trying to overwrite ‘/opt/ros/humble/include/admittance_controller_parameters/admittance_controller_parameters.hpp’, which is also in package ros-humble-admittance-controller 2.33.0-1jammy.20240311.114411
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)

Error: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/ros-humble-mp2p-icp_1.3.0-1jammy.20240319.074232_amd64.deb (–unpack):

Error: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/ros-humble-mp2p-icp_1.3.0-1jammy.20240319.074232_amd64.deb (–unpack):
trying to overwrite ‘/opt/ros/humble/include/tsl/robin_growth_policy.h’, which is also in package ros-humble-mola-metric-maps 1.0.0-1jammy.20240320.190903
trying to overwrite ‘/opt/ros/humble/include/tsl/robin_growth_policy.h’, which is also in package ros-humble-mola-metric-maps 1.0.0-1jammy.20240320.190903

Errors were encountered while processing:
/var/cache/apt/archives/ros-humble-generate-parameter-library-example_0.3.8-1jammy.20240311.113305_amd64.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/ros-humble-mp2p-icp_1.3.0-1jammy.20240319.074232_amd64.deb
[/quote]